# youtube api v3 search returns different results from youtube site

Tags: search, youtube-api

I'm trying to do a search on the v3 api using this url:
[https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id,snippet&channelId=UCtVd0c0tGXuTSbU5d8cSBUg&maxResults=10&order=date&q=game&key=[API_KEY]](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id,snippet&channelId=UCtVd0c0tGXuTSbU5d8cSBUg&maxResults=10&order=date&q=game&key=%5bAPI_KEY%5d)

but this returns me only one playlist.

When I do this search on youtube site directly it returns more results to me:
https://www.youtube.com/user/YouTubeDev/search?query=game

Why this happens, is there something wrong that I'm doing?

Answer (score 1):

We ran into a similar issue when we tried to search for large amounts of content. This is especially evident if you set the time range you're looking for using publishedAfter and publishedBefore to a very small range (say for example 1 hour). Even when we get to very small result sets (you can only paginate around 20 times on the API using pageToken back when we tried it, so it was when our totalResults were less than 1,000), we were finding actually only as little as 540 items.

We reached out to YouTube and our contacts there confirmed that the totalResults are just an estimate, and are not actually accurate. You may get up to the amount of items specified, but there is no guarantee that you will get exactly that. Your best bet is to capture as much as you can, and scan for data using a different time range.

Source: Reddit

Answer (score 0):

In the first one you are using search->list method. Which is searching for channels?

In the second one you are doing a playlist search inside the channel.
You can do the same on API via [playlists->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list).

(Or if you want the videos inside the channel straight, use [videos->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list))

Comment: My idea was to do a search for videos/playlist, this is what I tried to do on the first link. 
On the second the idea was to do the same, but on youtube site, so there I was also searching for videos and playlist, and not only playlists.
I tried to look here in the api and the playlists->list and videos->list doesn't support the q parameter that I use in the search, so I believe this wouldn't help isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bug. If so and not yet filed, you can file it here: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list?q=label%3aAPI-YouTube

The problem seems to be caused by the parameter order=date.
Adding order to the "YouTube query" (using channel): https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCtVd0c0tGXuTSbU5d8cSBUg/search?query=game&order=date ,is not different. However omitting order from the "api request" gives the same result (6 items): https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id,snippet&channelId=UCtVd0c0tGXuTSbU5d8cSBUg&maxResults=10&q=game&key=YOUR-API-KEY-HERE
Note, that with using order=date in the api request only 1 item is shown, while the same response shows totalResults": 6 (which seems to be right). I did not try all, but using order=relevance does not give this problem.